System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Success!, Actual: Credentials are already set!
My code coverage is 86% and i want it to be atleast 90%... When I test it im getting this error System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Success!, Actual: Credentials are already set!
@isTest
public class RewardsCalloutServiceTest {
    @isTest static void testSubmitUsersForRewardCallout() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new RewardsCalloutServiceMock());

        // Create test data for Wellness Journey
        List<Wellness_Journey__c> journeys = new List<Wellness_Journey__c>();
        User testUser = [SELECT Id, Name, Username, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            Wellness_Journey__c journey = new Wellness_Journey__c(
                OwnerId = testUser.Id
            );
            journeys.add(journey);
        }
        insert journeys;

        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new WellnessJourneyRewardsBatch());
        Test.stopTest();

        // Assertions to validate the behavior can be added here
        Integer statusCode = RewardsCalloutService.submitUsersForRewardCallout(JSON.serialize(journeys));
        System.assertEquals(200, statusCode, 'The HTTP status code should be 200');
    }
}


This question is similar to: How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
